# Bluetooth headset controller buttons stopped working on macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, headphones, spotify

Up until today all of the buttons on my Sony headphones worked in controlling my Spotify app. I could play/pause skip tracks etc.

After having a meeting on zoom today, all of the buttons except volume stopped working. I tried restarting Spotify, restarting my headphones, making sure zoom was shut, restarting my computer (basically restarting everything) but nothing seems to be working. The only solutions I have found for this issue are very old. Any ideas?

Comment: Just because a solution is old doesn't mean it's no longer valid.  However, your question title says "...on MacBook Pro."  does this mean the problem is limited to the MBP or have you tried this on other computers?  If you haven't, I suggest you do so that you can narrow down the problem to either your Mac or to your headphones.

Comment: @Allan In this case it does as the solutions require old software that don't have modern versions compatible with my OS. Yes, the headphones work just fine with other peices of hardware

Comment: If that’s the case, we need to know which MacBook, what version of macOS and what these “older versions of software” were?  What new software are you using now?

Comment: @Allan I didn't say I was using a newer version. I can't use any version of the software stated in old solutions.  I said, the solutions require software which is not compatible with modern distributions of my os. I'm using Mojave in a 2019 MacBook pro 13 inch with i7. Most solutions site this softwarehttps://github.com/jguice/mac-bt-headset-fix which has not seen an update in quite some time

Comment: You said it requires “old software not compatible with your modern distribution of your OS.”  The logical question is “what software are you using now?” Did you try the fix?  As the link seems to be for Spotify, did you determine that the headset works with other Apps or is it just Spotify where you have the issue?

Comment: @allan, i tried the fix. it did not work. This is in reference to the software referenced in the old solutions. I am not using any software fix right now. The headset controllers don't work with my macbook pro in general.. Spotify, or any other app on my MBP, but works with other hardware.